# VideoView crashes after long time playing

Tags: android, video, crash, xamarin.android, android-videoview

I have a application that play videos in loop forever. I'm facing an issue that the VideoView seems to crash after a long time playing (usually 2 to 3 days).

Some commentaries about what is happening:

- My entire code within Try - Catch blocks, but the error is not being catched by them. (that's why I didn't post any logs)
- It's not being catched by UnhandledException neither (or is being catched but not logged on my server). I created a custom ApplicationContext class and it was suppose to log (send the error to the server) when an UnhandledException happens.
- MP4 videos seems to play for a longer time then WMV.
- Memory is being watched and it keeps almost static (it usually starts with 649mb and after two days playing it still have 618mb free)
- There are two types of visual errors:

  1 - The screen turns black (I believe that happens when the error occur during video changing)

  2 - The video freezes (but the application keeps responding to my server)

I can't post logs because there are none. I can't post my code because it would be necessary to post the entire solution, but I do can send someone my app and give instructions on how to use.

If you don't know what may be happening, **any ideas of how to find the error message would help a lot**.

Thank you all.

Comment: Any update on this? I'm having the same problem when repeating 150 short videos continuously for 2 days